# LINQ to SQL DataContext Caching

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL as my DAL layer and during unit test I found out that my objects are not being returned from database but from the DataContext cache.

The strange thing is that when the objects are returned from the cache why does it require a separate call to the database to fetch all the fields.

Anyway, I implemented a ClearCache method that will clear out the cache. But I am only clearing the cache in the unit test and not in the API code.

The reason is that once the object is inserted it is good to load from the cache then to fetch it again from the database.

What do you think?

**UPDATE**:

```
public static void ClearCache(this EStudyModelDataContext context)
        {
            const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var method = context.GetType().GetMethod("ClearCache", Flags);
            method.Invoke(context, null);
        }
```

Comment: Are you re-using your DataContext instances?

Comment: Yes, I am re-using DataContext instances!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that L2S will return items from the cache when it can. I learned about this the hard way. A clean way to handle this is to do a context.RefreshRow after each Insert and Update operation. This refreshes the cache and guarantees the cache is current.

Comment: Updated post! I have a ClearCache method. I think the L2S cache does not cache the entire object but only the identity of the object. That is why it fetches the object from the database. I may be wrong! 

Also, I think I only want to do this in unit test and not in actual code. I accomplished it by using Repository pattern and interfaces.

Comment: It has been my experience that L2S does not retrieve the entire object from the database, but gets it from cache. I have verified this by looking at the output via the context.Log method. When the object exists in cache, no SQL call was made to the DB.

Comment: That is weird because I can see the query fired from L2S using SQL profiler for the select statement. I inserted the object first and then retrieved it using Id.

Comment: I am confused. DataContext does not have a RefreshRow.

Answer (score 3):

in my case work only with 4 bindings:

```
DATACONTEXT.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "ClearCache",
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null, DATACONTEXT, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one big caveat to manually calling 'ClearCache' - it is that you're doing exactly that!  So - if you had any prior database operations (pending), you just flushed them.  You have to be very careful that you haven't walked on other "On Submit" changes.  I learned this the hard way - so I had to add a few more 'SubmitChanges' statements into my code - as a direct result of implementing ClearCache after some stored procedure executions (bulk deletes).