# How to Revert Associated Records using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a database for an enrollment system and in it there are two tables, `Person` and `Class`, which have a many-to-many relationship. Between them, there is a join table named `Enrollment`. The following code shows the aforementioned `Person` and `Enrollment` classes:

```
[Table]
public class Person
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column()]
    public string FirstName;

    [Column()]
    public string LastName;

    private EntitySet<Enrollment> _enrollment = new EntitySet<Enrollment>();

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Name = "FK_Enrollment_Person", Storage = "_enrollment", OtherKey = "StudentId", ThisKey = "Id")]
    public IList<Enrollment> Enrollment
    {
        get { return _enrollment; }
        set { _enrollment.Assign(value); }
    }
}

[Table]
public class Enrollment
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column()]
    public int StudentId;

    [Column()]
    public int ClassId;

    [Column()]
    public DateTime EnrollDate;

}
```

Also there is a subclass of `DataContext` to represent the database:

```
[Database]
public class Database : DataContext
{
    public Database()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnection"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

So I can retrieve the records of `Person` and their associated `Enrollment` records as follows:

```
    Database db = new Database();
    var people = db.GetTable<Person>();
```

What I need is to have a way to revert those records back to their original states after modification. I tried `DataContext.Refresh` method and it did work on Person but did not work on the associated recrords of `Enrollment`.

In the following example I modify the `EnrollDate` property of the `Enrollment` records but they do not rollback after I call `DataContext.Refresh`.

```
        Database db = new Database();
        var people = db.GetTable<Person>();

        var enrolledPeople = people.Where(o => o.Enrollment.Count > 0);
        foreach(var person in enrolledPeople)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Original Enroll Date:");
            foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
                enrollment.EnrollDate = DateTime.Now;
            }

            person.Enrollment.Add(new Enrollment() );

            db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, person);

            Console.WriteLine("Enroll Date After being refreshed:");
            foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
            }                
        }
```

Does anyone know an approach to revert associated records using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: I can see you have made two changes in all. 1. You added a new enrollment 2. Changed the enrollment dates of all the existing enrollments. I believe your enrollDate property of enrollments associated with a person isn't refreshing. But what about the newly added enrollment? After the refresh do you also see the new enrollment object in the collection while iterating using foreach?

Comment: Those are just two examples where the Refresh method does not work, so they just stay whatever they are after the modification as if the method hadn't been called.

Comment: I checked it in sql profiler that refresh method is sending a query to get data of persons only but when we reiterate its enrollments property it uses the cached copy even if you repeat the GetTable<Person> API call.

Comment: Even clear cache doesn't seem to be of any help in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141208/linq-to-sql-datacontext-caching

Comment: Thanks for the great information I've figured out a way to solve the problem base on your suggestion.

Comment: If your problem is resolved then you might want to accept any one of the provided answers as an answer to your question so that community can focus on other unsolved problems under the tags you have used in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on RBT's answer, I also added a piece of code to discard new-added records:

```
    Database db = new Database();
    var people = db.GetTable<Person>();
    var enrollments = db.GetTable<Enrollment>();

    var enrolledPeople = people.Where(o => o.Enrollment.Count > 0);
    foreach(var person in enrolledPeople)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original Enroll Date:");
        foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
            enrollment.EnrollDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        person.Enrollment.Add(new Enrollment() );

// beginning of rollback
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, person);
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, enrollments);

        for (int i= person.Enrollment.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if (person.Enrollment[i].Id == 0)
                person.Enrollment.RemoveAt(i);
        }
// end of rollback   

        Console.WriteLine("Enroll Date After being refreshed:");
        foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
        }                
    }
```

Because the IDs always start from one in my case, records whose IDs are zero must not have been submitted to the database.

Comment: Nice effort Isaac!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to refresh the records of Enrollment table in your dataContext as shown below. There are two lines which need to be added in the code. I've marked them in comment for your reference.

```
   Database db = new Database();
    var people = db.GetTable<Person>();
    //Modified line # 1
    var enrollments = db.GetTable<Enrollment>();


    var enrolledPeople = people.Where(o => o.Enrollment.Count > 0);
    foreach(var person in enrolledPeople)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original Enroll Date:");
        foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
            enrollment.EnrollDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        person.Enrollment.Add(new Enrollment() );

        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, person);
        //Modified line # 2
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, enrollments);

        Console.WriteLine("Enroll Date After being refreshed:");
        foreach (var enrollment in person.Enrollment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enrollment.EnrollDate);
        }                
    }
```

**Note**: Only caveat to this is that it will not discard the new record you have added into the enrollments. It will only refresh the records of the `Enrollment` table with the latest values for the rows which are already present in the database.

Comment: Yeah, it does work. And I can discard the new record by checking its ID so that's not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the enrollment objects. Enrollements are not "owned" by a person. They are not part of it. They are independent entities. Refresh works on the one entity you pass in.

Imagine Refresh refreshed an entire object graph. Databases tend to be cyclically connected. A single Refresh call could end up affecting *all objects* and change it's behavior randomly depending on what is loaded and mapped.